# Python - Multiprocessing and external program

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I am looking for a way to do multiprocessing (specifically use `Process` and `Queue`) but with an external program instead of a Python class/module. Is this possible? I don't want to use the `subprocess` module because it doesn't provide good message passing like `multiprocessing` does or at least I wasn't able to use it the same way as multiprocessing -- Running a process, sending a task every now and then and reading the results while keeping the process alive.

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: unless you do some shared ctypes tomfoolery, subprocess is going to be your best bet. multiprocessing is only built to handle snippets of python code

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Turns out my problem with using subprocess was pretty dumb. I had trouble communicating but flushing the subprocess' stdout every time fixed it.

Comment: You could also change the buffering of std in/out, but flushing is generally a better idea imao